# possibly wrong usage of 〜ば〜た in grammar book

Tags: grammar

In on of the grammar books I found a question:

> 運転して（　）、急に車の前へ犬が飛び出してビックリした。
>   1)いるなら　２）いれば　３）いても　４）いたら

The correct answer is marked as 2. Is it correct? I have never seen 〜ば used in such way, the only examples I see on the internet are like:

> ３０分前に出発すれば良かったのに

Is it possible there is a mistake in that book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is #4 「いたら」, not #2 「いれば」. You would say:

> 運転して**いたら** or 運転して**いると**、急に車の前へ犬が飛び出してビックリした。

運転しているなら(#1)/いれば(#2) would be like "if I am/was driving", and 運転していても(#3) would be like "even if I was driving". 運転していたら(#4) can mean either "if I was driving" or "when I was driving" (Here it means the latter). I think いたら sounds a bit more casual than いると.